# Move tab of file Explorer between Windows

Tags: windows-11

On my personnal PC, I can move tab of Explorer to another window (insider version with ViveTool hack).

My pro PC run Windows 11 22H2 and I cannot upgrade it (admin restrictions ).

I have 2 questions about Windows explorer on last official version (23H2):

- does this version support drag and drop move of tab between 2 windows of explorer ?
- does this version fix the annoying bug of randomly apparition of explorer windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1386413/windows-11-explorer-randomly-pops-out) ?

I've not found information about that on the Internet.

Comment: I personally use TidyTabs to basically group any program with its own tabs. I can then drag and drop any tab to another window. Maybe you want something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 11 23H2, and I can testify that drag-and-drop
tabs between Explorer windows works well.

You have to be careful to drop the tab on the tabs bar, or the
operation will fail and the tab may open inside a new Explorer
window (this behavior might change in the future).

I haven't experienced the bug of Explorer randomly popping out,
but can't say if it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 11 Pro 23H2 (newest) and a native installation with no 3rd party start or taskbar apps.

Drag and Drop Explorer tabs works properly on several Windows 11 Pro 23H2 machines here and also on Windows 11 Insider.

So as far as I can see, to your first question, this appears to be a reliable advancement of Windows 11.

To your second question, I use a native installation and have not experienced this bug. The Microsoft source says it is random.